# Android - Exporting event to local calendar

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to export an event to the local calendar by an intent which looks like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", 1407880800000);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", 1408053600000);
    intent.putExtra("title", helper.events.get(position).optString("name"));
    intent.putExtra("description",  helper.events.get(position).optString("description"));
    intent.putExtra("eventLocation", helper.events.get(position).optString("address"));
    intent.putExtra("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

The dates are converted from a unix timestamp to milliseconds and should start:
**12 Aug 2014 22:00:00** and finish **14 Aug 2014 22:00:00**. But when ever I insert it in to the calendar it adds +2 hours to the time so I get the 13th at 00:00:00 and end time 15th 00:00:00.

How can I insert the correct time?

EDIT: If I remove timezone or change it to anything else but GMT does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to convert the milliseconds I had to a string, then used simpledateformat and converted it back to milliseconds, adding the default timezone to the simpledateformat. Like this:

```
public void exportEventToCalendar() {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat startFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.date_format));
        startFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date dateS = startFormat.parse(Methods.getMethods().getDate(getActivity(), helper.events.get(position).optLong("starts"), R.string.date_format));
        long start = dateS.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat endFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.date_format));
        endFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date dateE = endFormat.parse(Methods.getMethods().getDate(getActivity(), helper.events.get(position).optLong("ends"), R.string.date_format));
        long end = dateE.getTime();

        Log.e("Start", "" + start);
        Log.e("Ends", "" + end);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, start);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, end);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, helper.events.get(position).optString("name"));
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,  helper.events.get(position).optString("description"));
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, helper.events.get(position).optString("address"));
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're in GMT+2 somehow? If so, your local calendar will display the event in your timezone, adding 2 hours.

In that case you would need to set the correct eventTimezone to TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02")

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Just tried and no difference